# Get every regex match one by one with their positions

Tags: c++, regex

I need to get all regex matches and their positions.

For example, I have this regex:

```
std::regex r("(a)|(b)|(c)");
```

And this input text:

```
std::string text("abcab");
```

Now I want to loop the matches there in every loop I can access all occurrences from one match. So in first loop I could get "a" at position 0 and "a" at position 3. In second loop it'd be "b" at 1 and "b" at 4. And in third loop it'd be "c" at position 2. How can I do this?

Currently I have every regex part separately (regex for `(a)`, `(b)` and `(c)`) and go through them one by one. But there are quite many of them so I'm looking for better/faster solution.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator

Comment: Something like [this](https://ideone.com/QAqBGn)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need to know what match number is the current match.

Comment: I don't mind having multiple regexes but if they are separate, I also need to ensure that I don't have same matches. For example, I firstly look for "ab" and then for "a" and "b", so in every match I need to loop through the whole container I'm storing the matches in, to ensure that the new match isn't already (partially) in it.

Comment: Ok, I guess you need to declare string vectors to store the captured values in, and then check which alternative branch matched, and add it to the corresponding vector. Something like https://ideone.com/C6sOfo. Does it sound like a plan?

Comment: Don't forget to optimize your `regex` using `std::regex e("pattern", std::regex_constants::optimize);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare string vectors to store the captured values in, and then check which alternative branch matched, and add it to the corresponding vector.

Here is a [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/C6sOfo):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::regex r("(a)|(b)|(c)");
    std::string s = "abcab";
    std::vector<std::string> astrings; // Declare the vectors to 
    std::vector<std::string> bstrings; // populate with the contents
    std::vector<std::string> cstrings; // of capturing groups

    for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
           i != std::sregex_iterator();
           ++i)
    {
        std::smatch m = *i;
        if (m[1].matched) {                 // Check if Group 1 matched and 
            astrings.push_back(m[1].str()); // Put a value into a string vector
        }
        else if (m[2].matched) {            // Check if Group 2 matched and 
            bstrings.push_back(m[2].str()); // Put a value into b string vector
        }
        else if (m[3].matched) {             // Check if Group 3 matched and 
            cstrings.push_back(m[3].str());  // Put a value into c string vector
        }
    }

    // Printing vectors - DEMO
    for (auto i: astrings)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (auto i: bstrings)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (auto i: cstrings)
        std::cout << i << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

You may also consider using `std::regex_constants::optimize` flag when declaring the regexp (see [Galik's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36544720/get-every-regex-match-one-by-one-with-their-positions#comment60692471_36544720)).

Comment: Thank you. This works but still, it's way too slow than I need. I've got over 60 regexes and input text can be thousands of lines so I have to solve it some other way. But still, thanks! :)

Comment: Well, perhaps, regex is not the best tool for your task then. Or, as I suspect, the problem is somewhere in one or a couple of your patterns that might cause performance issues (that is a common problem with regexps).